# How to style the 2nd td where the parent tr has a certain style?

Tags: html, css

I would like to style the 2nd td of rows where the tr has a class of `rowRegular` for table with id="tbl"

I have the following markup:

```
<table id="tbl">
  <tr class="rowX1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowRegular">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Style me</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowRegular">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Style me</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I have the following css:

```
.rowRegular #tbl tr td:nth-child(2) { background-color: green; }
```

Needless to say, the background color is not applied.  What am I missing?

Comment: `#tbl  tr.rowRegular td:nth-child(2) { background-color: green; } `

Comment: #tbl is outside rowRegular in the markup, so must be before rowRegular in the css declaration. Also, rowRegular is on the tr-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here: (1) an incorrect ordering of CSS selectors, and (2) over-specificity in your selectors. Solving the first gets the desired behavior, but addressing the second helps you to avoid the first problem, and makes for more maintainable CSS.

The best and simplest version of what you want is probably this:

```
.rowRegular > td:nth-child(2)
```

I'll get into why that is in just a bit, but first let's take a look at your code and work out the issue. Here's your current CSS declaration:

```
.rowRegular #tbl tr td:nth-child(2)
```

Let's break it down from right to left — where the rightmost selector pinpoints the element you're trying to target, and those to the left specify ancestors that allow us to home in on the target. This code says that you're trying to select:

1. every second `td` element within a common parent,
2. anywhere within a common `tr` element,
3. anywhere within any element with id `#tbl`
4. anywhere within any element of class `.rowRegular`

This doesn't reflect the order of the elements in your HTML, so Temani is right in suggesting that you change the order of the selectors. He suggested this:

```
#tbl tr.rowRegular td:nth-child(2)
```

This gets the order right, but you still have an issue of over-specificity, which makes your CSS less clear, less readable, and more prone to errors. It's best practice to [try to keep your specificity low](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-keeping-css-specificity-low/), both for readability and for maintainability. Unless you have a compelling reason to target by ID or to specify the element along with a class, you should simplify your selectors.

So here, again, is probably the best and simplest version, unless there are other constraints:

```
.rowRegular > td:nth-child(2)
```

It isn't necessary to specify that `.rowRegular` is a `tr` element, and it likely isn't necessary to specify that it's in a table with id `#tbl`. It's enough — and easier to read and maintain — if you select for the class alone.

Also, notice that I'm using a [direct descendent or "child combinator"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) (`>`), to be distinguished from the [general descendent combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors), which is just a space. This isn't strictly necessary in this case, but it is good practice. This is because the general descendant combinator will check every descendant of `.rowRegular`, so that it's possible to inadvertently select children of children in addition to the targeted element. This is actually a common problem with nth-child selectors (though less likely here since you rarely nest tables outside of HTML email).

The [danger of over-specificity](https://www.creativebloq.com/css3/avoid-css-mistakes-10135080) is that you end up writing more CSS than you need to, which becomes unwieldy and difficulty to read, and then you continue to keep writing more, upping the ante on yourself to override the specificity of your earlier CSS. And before you know it, you have to put the `!important` annotation on rules to get anything done.

Comment: Excellent explanation.  I wish there was a course that just took rookie mistakes like mine and walked through everything that was wrong and how to fix them.